# How to create tables in SNMP MIB

Tags: snmp, mib

I am kinda new to SNMP and trying to create first MIB. Since now we only used one level of SNMP nodes. Now, we are going to have agent which provides diagnostic to multiple PCI cards and each card operates multiple inputs.
We have prepared following structure

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.companyID.productFamily
                                   .numberOfCards
                                   .card
                                        .indexC (index of card in system)
                                               .parameterC1
                                               .parameterC2
                                               .numberOfInputs
                                               .input
                                                     .indexI (index of input on card)
                                                            .parameterI1
                                                            .parameterI2
```

Is this the correct approach? I don't really understand how tables work in SNMP and wasn't able to find some suitable guide. Please hint me with how to do correctly indexed tables.

Answer (score 1):

After some research I think I am able to answer myself. Correct tree should be something like this:

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.companyID.productFamily
                               .numberOfCards
                               .cardsTable
                                    .cardRow
                                           .parameterC1.indexC
                                           .parameterC2.indexC
                                           .numberOfInputs.indexC
                               .inputsTable
                                    .inputsRow
                                           .parameterI1.indexC.indexI
                                           .parameterI2.indexC.indexI
```

Comment: Can you share your resulting MIB with us ?